# FPDF can we use require or include to add functions back to the original class?

Tags: php, fpdf

Question also is: Can functions be added to FPDF from external sources at all????

I would like to separate out some "items" functions from the original FPDF class and use include or require to add them back to that class. All the "included" functions would be a sort of "template" for my items. I will have a varying number of items/functions. Having all the functions in the original class would make the code very long. I would like to have the functions for each set of "items" in its own php file and then include it in the class.... Is this possible?

Here is an error I get: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PDF_receipt::Item1() in /home/....

```
   <?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php'); // FPDF VERSION 1.81 12/20/2015
class PDF_receipt extends FPDF {
public function __construct ($orientation = 'L', $unit = 'pt', $format = 'Letter', $margin = 33) {
        parent::__construct($orientation, $unit, $format, $margin);
    $this->SetTopMargin($margin);
    $this->SetLeftMargin($margin);
    $this->SetRightMargin($margin); 
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $margin);
}

// HEADER FUNCTION
function Header() {
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 16);
    $this->SetXY(30, 15);
    $this->SetFillColor(232, 249, 169);
    $this->SetTextColor(100);
    $this->Cell(0, 30, "APPAREL KITCHEN ONLINE ORDERING", 0, 1, 'C', true);
    $this->Image("images/ttdinfocopy.jpg",40,55,225,60,"jpg", "");
    $this->Image("images/mens-ladies-keiki.jpg",535,58,200,42,"jpg", "");
}

// ORDER SUBMIT DATE FUNCTION
function SubmitDate() {   
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);
    $this->SetXY(150, 245);
    $this->Cell(222, 10, 'Order Date: ' . date('F jS Y g:i:s A') . ' AZ time', 0, 1);
}

// HEADINGS TABLE CONSTRUCTION FUNCTION
function QtyTable() {
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFillColor(240);
    $this->SetLineWidth(1);
    $this->SetXY(30, 233);  
    $this->Cell(100, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(300, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(95, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);    
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);    
    $this->Cell(28, 12, "3-6", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);    
    $this->Cell(28, 12, "6-12", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 12, "12-18", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 12, "18-24", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(38, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);        
    $this->Ln(10);
    $this->Cell(97, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(300, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(95, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);    
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);    
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "Month", 'LR', 0, 'C', true);   
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "Month", 'LR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "Month", 'LR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "Month", 'LR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(28, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(38, 10, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);        
    $this->Ln(10);  
    $this->Cell(97, 20, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(300, 20, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);
    $this->Cell(95, 20, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);    
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "2", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);  
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "4", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);  
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "6", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "8", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "10", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "12", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "O/S", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(38, 20, "", '0', 0, 'C', false);        
    $this->Ln(18);  
    $this->Cell(97, 20, "Item Name", '1', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(300, 20, "Description", '1', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(95, 20, "Color", '1', 0, 'C', true);    
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "XS", '1', 0, 'C', true);   
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "SM", '1', 0, 'C', true);   
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "MD", '1', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "LG", '1', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "XL", '1', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "XX", '1', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(28, 20, "XXX", '1', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(38, 20, "Total", '1', 1, 'C', true);
}

//   PLACEHOLDER ROW SO ITEM ROWS HAVE A STARTING POINT AFTER FORM SUBMITTED
function submittedItemRowPositioner() {
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $this->SetFillColor(242);
    $this->SetLineWidth(0); 
    $this->SetXY(33, 271);
    $this->Cell(97, 20, '', '1', 0, 'L');
    $this->Cell(300, 20, '', '1', 0, 'L');
    $this->Cell(95, 20, '', '1', 0, 'L');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, '', '1', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, '', '1', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, '', '1', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, '', '1', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, '', '1', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, '', '1', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, '', '1', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(38, 20, '', '1', 1, 'C');
}

function MessageBottom() {        
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $this->SetFillColor(242);
    $this->SetXY(35, 560);
    $message = "Thank you for your online order. If you have any questions, you can email us at the following address: ";
    $this->Write(12, $message);
}

function EmailAddress() {
    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'U', 10);
    $this->SetTextColor(1, 162, 232);
    $this->SetXY(488, 559.5);
    $this->Write(12, "orders@xxxxxxx.com", "mailto:orders@xxxxxxxns.com?subject=New Order From Ka'anapali&body=Link to new PO: http://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/php-pdf-practice/receipts/".$_POST['ponum'].".pdf");
}

function Footer() {
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetXY(30, 575);
    $this->Cell(0, 35, "Apparel Designs", 'T', 0, 'C');
}

********#I would like to put the functions below in their own file and "include" it here. There could be 40 - 60 item functions #********

//   KA'ANAPALI ITEMS BELOW
//   ITEM 1
function Item1() {
    if (isset($_POST["item1Qty"][0]) && !empty($_POST["item1Qty"][0]) || 
    isset($_POST["item1Qty"][1]) && !empty($_POST["item1Qty"][1]) ||
    isset($_POST["item1Qty"][2]) && !empty($_POST["item1Qty"][2]) ||
    isset($_POST["item1Qty"][3]) && !empty($_POST["item1Qty"][3]) ||
    isset($_POST["item1Qty"][4]) && !empty($_POST["item1Qty"][4]) ||
    isset($_POST["item1Qty"][5]) && !empty($_POST["item1Qty"][5])) {
    $item1Qty = $_POST['item1Qty'];
    $item     = $_POST['item1'];
    $desc     = $_POST['desc1'];
    $color    = $_POST['color1'];
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $this->SetFillColor(242);
    $this->SetLineWidth(1); 
    $this->SetX(33);
    $this->Cell(97, 20, $item, 'LRB', 0, 'L');
    $this->Cell(300, 20, $desc, 'LRB', 0, 'L');
    $this->Cell(95, 20, $color, 'LRB', 0, 'L');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item1Qty[0], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item1Qty[1], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item1Qty[2], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item1Qty[3], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item1Qty[4], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item1Qty[5], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, '', 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(38, 20, array_sum($item1Qty), 'LRB', 1, 'C');
}
}
//   ITEM 2
function Item2() {
    if (isset($_POST["item2Qty"][0]) && !empty($_POST["item2Qty"][0]) || 
    isset($_POST["item2Qty"][1]) && !empty($_POST["item2Qty"][1]) ||
    isset($_POST["item2Qty"][2]) && !empty($_POST["item2Qty"][2]) ||
    isset($_POST["item2Qty"][3]) && !empty($_POST["item2Qty"][3]) ||
    isset($_POST["item2Qty"][4]) && !empty($_POST["item2Qty"][4]) ||
    isset($_POST["item2Qty"][5]) && !empty($_POST["item2Qty"][5])) {
    $item2Qty = $_POST['item2Qty'];
    $item     = $_POST['item2'];
    $desc     = $_POST['desc2'];
    $color    = $_POST['color2'];               
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '');
    $this->SetFillColor(242);
    $this->SetLineWidth(1); 
    $this->SetX(33);
    $this->Cell(97, 20, $item, 'LRB', 0, 'L');
    $this->Cell(300, 20, $desc, 'LRB', 0, 'L');
    $this->Cell(95, 20, $color, 'LRB', 0, 'L');     
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item2Qty[0], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item2Qty[1], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item2Qty[2], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item2Qty[3], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item2Qty[4], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, $item2Qty[5], 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(28, 20, '', 'LRB', 0, 'C');
    $this->Cell(38, 20, array_sum($item2Qty), 'LRB', 1, 'C');
}
}
//   ITEM 3, ITEM 4, etc........
```

Comment: There is functions/extend/inplement/traits/new and other ways to maintain your code. Use it instead of `include`

Comment: @Justinas could you elaborate a little more? I need to pull-in from a different directory, those sets of functions to the class...

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper classes that has this additional info:

```
class PDFHelper {
    public static function addCell($instance, ...) {
    }

    public static function setHeader($instance, ...) {
    }
}
```

And then in main class:

```
class PDFReceipt extends FPDF {
    PDFHelper::addCell($this, 95, 20, "Color");

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I'm new to classes...... can you point out where the actual importing of the functions that I want to include in the main class is happening?

Comment: @Bigfootbud At the top of file or use PHP autoloaders (google for it) that will automatically loads your class when needed.

Comment: Thanks! I just googled it... is there a way that we don't need to resort to "one last chance"??  Quote from the googled info on PHP AutoLoaders......."This provides the runtime one last chance to load the definition before PHP fails with an error"...

Comment: Question also is: Can functions be added to FPDF from external sources at all????

Comment: @Bigfootbud Yes, by extending FPDF class. `class MyPDF extends FPDF`